# How to create a REST endpoint without using an annotation?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I know that I can use `@GetMapping` and a Spring controller to expose a RESTFUL endpoint.
For example:

```java
@Controller
@ResponseBody
class CustomerRestController {

  private final CustomerService cs;

  CustomerRestController(CustomerService cs) {
    this.cs = cs;
  }

  @GetMapping("/customers")
  Collection<Customer> get() {
    return this.cs.getCustomers();
  }
}
```

Now I wonder how to achieve the same functionality without using annotations.
For example, consider the following code:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    var edb = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
        .build();

    var cs = new CustomerService(edb);
    var customers = cs.getCustomers();
    
    // Now I want to expose the list of customers as a RESTFUL endpoint.
  }
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: You want to return the content of `customers` to the caller of your endpoint? Why do you wan't to do it without annotations? If you don't want to use annotations you need to implement an own HttpServlet class by extending `HttpServlet` and handle the `doGet` method.

Comment: @Daniel Wosch: That's correct, In the example, I want to serve the content of `customers` to the caller of the endpoint. I want to do it without annotation to understand why is the annotation necessary in the first place, i.e., what's the benefit of using an annotation, compared with another approach.

Comment: The annotation is necessary to tell spring that this method handles an HTTP GET on the specified path. In short: All handlers get registered internally on startup. When a request arrives it gets the corresponding handler for this path and HTTP method out of this map. That's what the annotations @ Controller and @ GetMapping are used to. Mark them so spring loads them on startup and puts them into the RequestMappingHandler Map. Without the annotation you would need to register the handler manually.

Comment: @Daniel Wosch:  Thanks for the explanation. I understand. Do you know how to write the handlers manually? That's exactly what I'm asking for!

Comment: Your method annotated with `@GetMapping` **is** the handler so you have wrote it manually ;). But I think you would like to build the whole REST service manually without spring, right? Than I suggest to google a tutorial or something like that. Because this would to go beyond the constraints of stack overflow. Otherwise: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#registerMapping-org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Method-

Comment: `I suggest to google a tutorial or something like that` Wth kind of response is that? I think he is asking for something like that exactly, because any google on the topic will yield 1000 results that say how to use GetParam or some other combinations of other annotations. In a situation where the classloader for Spring doesn't have access to the class from another classloader, then Spring wont be able to scan these annotations; will it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a REST endpoint without Spring annotation, you will extend [HttpServlet Class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/httpservlet-class-in-java/) and override the doGet() method.

Here is an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvXQPCkP4X4